# People search under a Windows Store Application

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to do a people search inside my Windows Store Application by accessing contacts in people app in Windows 8 Start.

Do you have any ideas?

Regards,
Siva

Comment: Tell people what you have tried? add source code....

Comment: I have no idea on which API should I use for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the contacts programmatically. You can however open a [ContactPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR224913) and have the user select some contact information they want to share with your app.

Also the see the [corresponding sample](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Contact-Picker-App-sample-fc6677a1&ei=DuGMUYmHLumu4ASmrIB4&usg=AFQjCNGsjdmlCQFCVCMv6RUA11WpukDg9w&bvm=bv.46340616,d.bGE) from MSDN.